# подскажите как доделать прогресс бар на svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, svg-animation, progress-bar

Как сделать такой рейтинг или прогресс бар? я начал делать его на svg но как правильно его реализовать я не знаю.
нужно что бы это выглядело как прогресс бар, или что то наподобие рейтинга, который должен может кто знает как такое реализовать

```css
circle.default {
    stroke: #e8e8e8;
    fill: transparent;
    stroke-width: 10;
    stroke-dasharray: 80 24.5;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform: rotate(154deg);
}
```

```html
<svg class="progress-bars" width="500" height="500">
    
    
    

<circle class="default" cx="250" cy="250" r="200" stroke-linecap="round"></circle>
    
  
<circle class="default" cx="250" cy="250" r="200" stroke-linecap="round" style="
    stroke: #e91e63;
    stroke-dasharray: 80 6000;
"></circle><circle class="default" cx="250" cy="250" r="200" stroke-linecap="round" style="
    stroke: #e91e63;
    stroke-dasharray: 80 6000;
    transform: rotate(
184deg);
"></circle><circle class="default" cx="250" cy="250" r="200" stroke-linecap="round" style="
    stroke: #e91e63;
    stroke-dasharray: 43 6000;
    transform: rotate(
214deg);
"></circle><line x1="0" y1="500" x2="500" y2="500" style="stroke: rgb(255 255 255);stroke-width: 304px;"></line><circle class="" cx="250" cy="250" r="170" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#464646"></circle></svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы создать эффект прогресс бара, нужно сделать анимацию заполнения или закраски линий.

Вариант закраски пунктирной линии не решить с помощью только анимации `stroke-dasharray` и `stroke-dashoffset`, как это делается для сплошных линий.

Так как stroke-dasharray делит всю линию на сегменты и сдвигом с помощью stroke-dashoffset линия не будет рисоваться, будут просто двигаться сегменты.

***Для анимации заполнения сегментов можно использовать маску.***

Для этого на окружность с красными сегментами сверху добавляется точно такая же окружность с серыми сегментами. К этой окружности применена маска, которая прорезает серые сегменты, показывая тем самым красные сегменты, создавая иллюзию заполнения цветом.

```css
.container {
width:50vw;
height:50vh;
}
circle.default {
    stroke: #e8e8e8;
    fill: transparent;
    stroke-width: 10;
    stroke-dasharray: 80 24.5;
    }
  circle.red {
  stroke: #E91E63;
    fill: transparent;
    stroke-width: 10;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" class="progress-bars" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
 <defs>
   <mask id="mask"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
   <circle  fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="1256.6" stroke-dashoffset="1256.6" cx="250" cy="250" r="200" stroke-linecap="round">
     <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click" dur="10s" values="1256.6;0" fill="freeze" />
   </circle>
   
   </mask>
 </defs> 
 <g transform="rotate(140 250 250)">
 <circle class="default red" cx="250" cy="250" r="200" stroke-linecap="round"></circle>
 <circle class="default" mask="url(#mask)" cx="250" cy="250" r="200" stroke-linecap="round"></circle> 
 </g>
   <line x1="0" y1="500" x2="500" y2="500" style="stroke: rgb(255 255 255);stroke-width: 214px;"></line>
  <circle class="" cx="250" cy="250" r="170" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#464646"></circle> 
 <text y="50%" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" fill="white" font-size="36px" font-family="sans-serif">Click me</text> 
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если посмотреть внимательно на код первого ответа, то для получения дуги используется `circle`, низ которой экранирован линией с широкой строкой

`<line x1="0" y1="500" x2="500" y2="500" style="stroke: rgb(255 255 255);stroke-width: 214px;"></line>`

По большому счету это костыль, который проявится при изменении цвета фона.
Второй недостаток, если понадобится управлять анимацией с помощью input, то будет заметна задержка начала анимации, так как часть круга скрыта.

Чтобы избежать этого то лучше использовать для получения дуги [Elliptical Arc (A,a)](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=900#comm_a)

Из формулы ***Arc*** видно, что нам нужны координаты начала и конца дуги. Радиусы будут равны 200px

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<path  d="M76.8,350 A200,200 0 1 1 423.2,350"  />
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="progress-bars" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"> 
<path transform="rotate(3.5 250 250)" d="M76.8,350 A200,200 0 1 1 423.2,350" fill="none"  stroke="#e8e8e8"
stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray = "80  24.75"
stroke-linecap="round"  /> 
</svg>
```

Далее всё, как в первом ответе: над дугой с красными секторами, размещена точно такая же дуга с серыми секторами. Маска применяется к верхней дуге и при перемещении маски, серые сектора прорезаются, показывая тем самым нижние, красные сектора.

***Для управления анимацией добавлен input и вывод процентов выполнения***

```js
let total = velocity.getTotalLength(),
 input = document.querySelector("[type='range']"),
 txt = document.querySelector("#txt1");

input.addEventListener("input",()=>{  
  progress();  
})

window.addEventListener("load",()=>{  
  progress();  
})

function progress(){
  let val = Number(input.value);
  let dash = total * val / 100;
  let gap = total - dash;
  velocity.style.strokeDasharray = dash + " " + gap
txt.innerHTML = (val + "%"); 
}
```

```css
.container {
width:50vw;
height:50vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div><input id="size" type="range" min="0" step="1" max = "100" value="0" /></div>
<svg id="svg1" class="progress-bars"  viewBox="0 0 500 500"> 
<defs>
 <mask id="mask"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
   <path id="velocity" fill="none"  stroke="black" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray ="0,838"     stroke-linecap="round" d="M76.8,350 A200,200 0 1 1 423.2,350" >
       </path>
</mask> 
</defs>

 <g transform="rotate(3.5 250 250)" >
  <path fill="none"  stroke="#e91e63" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray = "80  24.75" stroke-linecap="round" d="M76.8,350 A200,200 0 1 1 423.2,350" />
  <path mask="url(#mask)" fill="none" stroke="#e8e8e8" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray = "80  24.75" stroke-linecap="round" d="M76.8,350 A200,200 0 1 1 423.2,350" />
  </g> 
   <circle class="" cx="250" cy="250" r="170" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#464646"></circle> 
 <text id="txt1" y="50%" x="50%" font-family="sans-serif" text-anchor="middle" font-size="56px" fill="white">0% </text> 
</svg>  
</div>
```